# Mapping a RESTful URL to a static HTML page, in a Java web app

Tags: java, spring, angularjs, spring-mvc

I have a Java web app that runs in JBoss. I'm adding a new web page for applying for a job, using AngularJS, and I'd like it respond to this (RESTful) URL:  `/job/<job id>/apply`

Since I'm new to Angular, I'm trying to figure out how to route the user's request of a URL like:

`GET /job/1/apply` (where "`1`" is the job id)

to a static HTML page in my web app, like `src/main/webapp/job/apply.html`. My plan is to have an `ng-app` and `ng-controller` specified in the `apply.html` template, which will call *back* to the server to fetch JSON to render in the view.

So how do I configure routing in my Java-based web app, so that requesting `/job/1/apply` yields `/job/apply.html`, and my controller JS code that's loaded by `apply.html` has easy access to the URL parameter "`1`"?

I've come up with several potential ways of accomplishing this, but none of them seem very simple or straightforward:

1. Use Spring MVC, write an @Controller that listens to the RESTful URL, and forwards the request to `apply.html`. (I'm not even using Spring MVC in this web app... yet.)
2. Use Spring MVC and the [`<mvc:resources>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources) or [`<mvc:view-controller>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-view-controller) element, to map the requested URL to the HTML page.
3. Use a web filter to rewrite the incoming URL to `/job/apply.html`.
4. Give up on using a RESTful URL, make the job ID a query param instead, and rename my `apply.html` to just `index.html` (so it gets picked up automatically). E.g. the user requests `/job/apply?jobId=1`, which maps to `webapp/job/apply/index.html`.

The thing I'm most uncertain about is whether the job ID in the request URL will be available to my angular controller code, in order to fetch data from the backend about that job.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect every request server-side to index.html when not requesting a file and use ng-route (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$route) to load the correct template with something like

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/job/:jobid/apply', {
        templateUrl: '/job/apply.html'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
  }
]);
```

If you can make use of the "html5 mode" of ngLocation (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location) that would be even cleaner for the end user.

Comment: My web app already has an `index.hmtl` file in the src/main/webapp root directory, so if I were to follow your directions I'd have to name it something else, or put it in a sub-directory.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how to "redirect every request server-side to index.html when not requesting a file." How do I know when I'm "not requesting a file"? I.e., how do I ensure that requests to `/job/1/apply` go to `index.html`, while requests to other resources continue as before?

Comment: You could configure your servlet to serve real file when it matches `*.html` in the request for example ?

Comment: I don't follow. Could you provide an example of what the `web.xml` configuration or servlet would look like?